# How to turn a Pandas Dataframe into a Dictionary of Dataframes by grouping columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that was built from 3D data and takes the form:

**Index**: A, B

**Columns**: 1.a, 1.b, 2.a, 2.b

I'm trying to unpack this into a dictionary mapping {A, B} to DataFrames with Index {1,2} and Columns {a,b}

**example input:**

`aa = pandas.DataFrame({'1.a':[1,2], '1.b':[3,4], '2.a':[5,6], '2.b':[7,8],  'index':['A', 'B']}).set_index('index')`

**goal output:**

`bb = {'A': pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,5], 'b':[3,7], 'index':[1,2]}), 'B': pandas.DataFrame({'a':[2,6], 'b':[4,8], 'index':[1,2]}) }`

Any thoughts?

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in df.groupby(level=0)}`?

Comment: Close but doesn't handle the new data frames correctly. A maps to the original row in your solution not to a new nonflat dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can change the column name to MultiIndex and unstack:

```
aa.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([a.split('.') for a in aa.columns])

out = {k:v.unstack() for k,v in aa.iterrows()}
```

Output:

```
{'A':    a  b
 1  1  3
 2  5  7,
 'B':    a  b
 1  2  4
 2  6  8}
```

Comment: Great! That's what I need. Thanks @Quang Hoang

Answer (score 0):

Split the columns and convert to MultiIndex; groupby on the first level of the MultiIndex index after stacking and create the dictionary

```
aa.columns = aa.columns.str.split(".", expand=True)
aa = aa.stack(level=0).rename_axis([None, "index"])
index = aa.index.get_level_values(0)
dict(list(aa.droplevel(0).groupby(index)))

{'A':        a  b
 index      
 1      1  3
 2      5  7,
 'B':        a  b
 index      
 1      2  4
 2      6  8}
```